# Bootstrap modal - how to display error message on submit

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal I have used within my application, when I click the submit button the modal is closed so the error message cannot be displayed.

Is there a way to prevent the page from being reloaded on submit?

Submit button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="PasswordChange" id="passwordChange" Text="Save" CssClass="btn btn-default"></asp:Button>
```

error message:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="error1"></asp:Label>
```

C#:

```
protected void PasswordChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currentPassword = cPassword.Text.ToString();
    string newPassword = nPassword.Text.ToString();
    string rePassword = rPassword.Text.ToString();

    db_connection();

    if (newPassword == rePassword)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Success" + newPassword + rePassword);
    }

    else
    {
        error1.Text = "Your passwords did not match, please try again";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refresh can be prevented using ajax e.g.

```
$("#passwordChange").click(function (event) {
    var n = $('#nPassword').val();
    var r = $('#rPassword').val();
    if (n != r || n == "") {
        $('.passwordError').show();
        event.preventDefault();          
    }
});
```